# Add related questions section

Tags: feature-request, android-app, related-questions

In the desktop browser version, I always have the habit of checking related questions. Many times you will find some gems there. I'm missing that in the Android app version. Please consider adding this feature.

Comment: Isn't there a place to make suggestions like this for the app? I don't use the apps; so I'm not sure. Just wondering.